# Retrieve one object from a list of objects, but not by index[], but by a name of a field

Tags: c#, json, list, object, search

At the end you can find the classes and Json file.

How to retrieve one object from a list of objects, not by index`[]` but by a name of a field? I need to retrieve the full object.

After I deserialize a Json file, I have a list of connections:

```
// List of connections are in m_ListTest
Test m_listTest = new Test();
```

At this point, I will like to retrieve a specific element from that list by passing the name of my connection

```
m_listTest.connections.name_connection == "Connection_A"
```

```
// Not by index
var ritorna_elemento_del_indice_selezionato_1 = m_listTest.connections[0];
// But by Name 
var ritorna_elemento_del_indice_selezionato_2 = m_listTest.connections.name_connection == "Connection_A";
```

Json file:

```
{
  "connections": [
    {
      "name_connection": "Connection_A",
      "imap_host": "imap.mail.com",
      "imap_user": "Email_A_@mail.com",
      "imap_pass": "aaaaaaaaaa",
      "imap_SSL_TLS": 993,
      "folder_to_open": [ "folder_A_/subfolder1", "folder_A_/subfolder2" ],
      "excluded_emails": [ "A1@mail.com", "A2@mail.com", "A3@mail.com" ]
    },
    {
      "name_connection": "Connection_B",
      "imap_host": "imap.mail.com",
      "imap_user": "Email_B_@mail.com",
      "imap_pass": "bbbbbbb",
      "imap_SSL_TLS": 993,
      "folder_to_open": [ "folder_B_/subfolder1", "folder_B_/subfolder2" ],
      "excluded_emails": [ "B1@mail.ru", "B2@mail.ru", "B3@mail.ru" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the class:

```
public class Test
{
    public Connection[] connections { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    public string name_connection { get; set; }
    public string imap_host { get; set; }
    public string imap_user { get; set; }
    public string imap_pass { get; set; }
    public int imap_SSL_TLS { get; set; }
    public string[] folder_to_open { get; set; }
    public string[] excluded_emails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is trivial using LINQ. `var item = connections.Single( x => x.name_connection == "Connection_A" );`

Comment: LINQ will be your best friend. =)
Otherwise, back to basic, use loop to iterate and check each element.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, the trivial solution would be to use LINQ

```
public static TestExtensions
{
    public static Connection? GetConnectionByName( this Test test, string name )
      => test.connections.FirstOrDefault( x => x.name_connection == name );
     // Consider string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison) , though
}

// usage
var item = test.GetConnectionByName("ConnectionA");
```

**If you need this in a very high frequency**, then you may want to build a more efficient lookup:

```
var connectionByName = test.connections.ToDictionary(x => x.name_connection, x => x);
// ^^ Do this _once_ and store the dictionary.
//    Also consider using the overload that lets you specifiy string comparison for the keys
var connection = connectionByName["ConnectionA"];
```

---

Despite duplicate being marked, I would like to keep this answer because in the dupe, I haven't seen an answer address the performance aspect.